# How to delete an item from a list inside of a class in python?

Tags: python

So i am building a shopping cart in python that has several commands such as add, remove, change, output item descriptions, output shopping cart, and quit(which terminates the function).

I am having trouble with removing an item from cart as my output is not the desired output.

So for example, for the input:

```
John Doe
February 1, 2016
a
Nike Romaleos
Volt color, Weightlifting shoes
189
2
a
Chocolate Chips
Semi-sweet
3
5
a
Powerbeats 2 Headphones
Bluetooth headphones
128
1
r
Chocolate Chips
o
q
```

When it says **r and then Chocolate Chips**, **Chocolate Chips should be removed from the Cart.**

My code so far:

```
class ItemToPurchase:
    def __init__(self, item_name='none', item_price=0, item_quantity=0, item_description='none'):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_price = item_price
        self.item_quantity = item_quantity
        self.item_description = item_description

    def print_item_cost(self):
        string = '{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name, self.item_quantity, self.item_price,
                                            (self.item_quantity * self.item_price))
        cost = self.item_quantity * self.item_price
        return string, cost

    def print_item_description(self):
        string = '{}: {}'.format(self.item_name, self.item_description)
        print(string, end='\n')
        return string


class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, customer_name='none', current_date='January 1, 2016', cart_items=[]):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.current_date = current_date
        self.cart_items = cart_items

    def add_item(self, string):
        print('\nADD ITEM TO CART', end='\n')
        item_name = str(input('Enter the item name:'))
        item_description = str(input('\nEnter the item description:'))
        item_price = int(input('\nEnter the item price:'))
        item_quantity = int(input('\nEnter the item quantity:\n'))
        self.cart_items.append(ItemToPurchase(item_name, item_price, item_quantity, item_description))

    def remove_item(self):
        print('\nREMOVE ITEM FROM CART', end='\n')
        string = str(input('Enter name of item to remove:\n'))
        i = 0
        for item in self.cart_items:
            if (item.item_name == string):
                del self.cart_items[i]
                i += 1
                flag = True
                break
            else:
                flag = False
        if (flag == False):
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')

    def modify_item(self):
        print('\nCHANGE ITEM QUANTITY', end='\n')
        name = str(input('Enter the item name: '))
        for item in self.cart_items:
            if (item.item_name == name):
                quantity = int(input('Enter the new quantity: '))
                item.item_quantity = quantity
                flag = True
                break
            else:
                flag = False
        if (flag == False):
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing modified.')

    def get_num_items_in_cart(self):
        num_items = 0
        for item in self.cart_items:
            num_items = num_items + item.item_quantity
        return num_items

    def get_cost_of_cart(self):
        total_cost = 0
        cost = 0
        for item in self.cart_items:

            cost = (item.item_quantity * item.item_price)

            total_cost += cost

        return total_cost

    def print_total(self):
        total_cost = self.get_cost_of_cart()
        if (total_cost == 0 and cost == 0):
            print('SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY')
        else:
            self.output_cart()

    def print_descriptions(self):
        print('\nOUTPUT ITEMS\' DESCRIPTIONS')
        print('{}\'s Shopping Cart - {}'.format(self.customer_name, self.current_date), end='\n')
        print('\nItem Descriptions', end='\n')
        for item in self.cart_items:
            print('{}: {}'.format(item.item_name, item.item_description), end='\n')

    def output_cart(self):
        new = ShoppingCart()
        print('OUTPUT SHOPPING CART', end='\n')
        print('{}\'s Shopping Cart - {}'.format(self.customer_name, self.current_date), end='\n')
        print('Number of Items:', new.get_num_items_in_cart(), end='\n\n')

        # IF NUMBER OF ITEMS IN THE OUTPUT CART IS 0...
        if new.get_num_items_in_cart() == 0:
            print('SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY')
        tc = 0
        for item in self.cart_items:
            print('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(item.item_name, item.item_quantity,
                                             item.item_price, (item.item_quantity * item.item_price)), end='\n')
            tc += (item.item_quantity * item.item_price)
        print('\nTotal: ${}'.format(tc), end='\n')


def print_menu(ShoppingCart):
    customer_Cart = newCart
    string = ''
    # declare the string menu
    menu = ('\nMENU\n'
            'a - Add item to cart\n'
            'r - Remove item from cart\n'
            'c - Change item quantity\n'
            'i - Output items\' descriptions\n'
            'o - Output shopping cart\n'
            'q - Quit\n')
    command = ''
    while (command != 'q'):
        string = ''
        print(menu, end='\n')
        command = input('Choose an option:\n')
        while (command != 'a' and command != 'o' and command != 'i' and command != 'r'
               and command != 'c' and command != 'q'):
            command = input('Choose an option:\n')
        if (command == 'a'):
            customer_Cart.add_item(string)
        if (command == 'o'):
            customer_Cart.output_cart()
        if (command == 'i'):
            customer_Cart.print_descriptions()
        if (command == 'r'):
            customer_Cart.remove_item()
        if (command == 'c'):
            customer_Cart.modify_item()


customer_name = str(input('Enter customer\'s name:'))
current_date = str(input('\nEnter today\'s date:\n\n'))
print('Customer name:', customer_name, end='\n')
print('Today\'s date:', current_date)
newCart = ShoppingCart(customer_name, current_date)
print_menu(newCart)
```

I tried

```
def remove_item(self):
    print('\nREMOVE ITEM FROM CART', end='\n')
    string = str(input('Enter name of item to remove:\n'))
    i = 0
    for item in self.cart_items:
        if (item.item_name == string):
            del self.cart_items[i]
            i += 1
            flag = True
            break
        else:
            flag = False
    if (flag == False):
        print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')
```

But my output (with the input) is:

```
REMOVE ITEM FROM CART
Enter name of item to remove:

MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
OUTPUT SHOPPING CART
John Doe's Shopping Cart - February 1, 2016
Number of Items: 6

Chocolate Chips 5 @ $3 = $15
Powerbeats 2 Headphones 1 @ $128 = $128

Total: $143

MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
```

When it should be:

```
REMOVE ITEM FROM CART
Enter name of item to remove:

MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
OUTPUT SHOPPING CART
John Doe's Shopping Cart - February 1, 2016
Number of Items: 3

Nike Romaleos 2 @ $189 = $378
Powerbeats 2 Headphones 1 @ $128 = $128

Total: $506

MENU
a - Add item to cart
r - Remove item from cart
c - Change item quantity
i - Output items' descriptions
o - Output shopping cart
q - Quit

Choose an option:
```

As you can see, my code is deleting the Nike Romaleos, $189, at Quantity 2
When it should be deleting the Chocolate Chips, $3, at Quantity 5.
I am not sure why it is deleting the wrong items, as I inputted Chocolate Chips right after 'r', which calls the

```
if (command == 'r'):
    customer_Cart.remove_item()
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated, but avoid using mutable types like lists as default arguments `cart_items=[]`, instead set it to `None` and then assign it inside the function.You may not call the constructor again here, but avoid this practice in general. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Also, your `output_cart` function creates a new instance of `ShoppingCart()` every time it is called, and then checks the size of that new, empty shopping cart...

Answer (score 1):

In the `remove_item` method, you are using `i` as an index to the items. Every time you loop, you only increment the value of `i` if the item name matches with the input string. What you should be doing is increment `i` no matter if the condition evaluates to `True` or not because it is the index. So, just move the increment statement outside the conditional block.

```py
def remove_item(self):
    print('\nREMOVE ITEM FROM CART', end='\n')
    string = str(input('Enter name of item to remove:\n'))
    i = 0
    for item in self.cart_items:
        if (item.item_name == string):
            del self.cart_items[i]
            flag = True
            break
        else:
            flag = False
        i += 1
    if (flag == False):
        print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')
```

This is a common mistake that every programmer makes. So, Python has provided a more elegant way to access indices of the elements in the loop.

```py
def remove_item(self):
    print('\nREMOVE ITEM FROM CART', end='\n')
    string = str(input('Enter name of item to remove:\n'))

    # We now don't need to handle the indices. Python will
    # do it for us. This magic happens with the help of `enumerate` function.
    for i, item in enumerate(self.cart_items):
        if (item.item_name == string):
            del self.cart_items[i]
            flag = True
            break
        else:
            flag = False
    if (flag == False):
        print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of following code in remove_item is wrong:

```
for item in self.cart_items:
    if (item.item_name == string):
        del self.cart_items[i]
        i += 1 # you only inc i when it match the string
        # also after delete, the index may be not consistent.
        flag = True
        break
    else:
        flag = False # you didn't inc i here.
```

you can use:

```
self.cart_items = [item for item in self.cart_items if item.item_name != string]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in `remove_item()` you are deleting the ith element from `cart_items` instead of deleting the index of the item which you are receiving as an input.

You can use `remove` instead of `del`.

This way you will not need the counter `i`

```
    def remove_item(self):
        print('\nREMOVE ITEM FROM CART', end='\n')
        string = str(input('Enter name of item to remove:\n'))

        for item in self.cart_items:
            if (item.item_name == string):
                self.cart_items.remove(item)
                flag = True
                break
            else:
                flag = False
        if (flag == False):
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')
```